# Who can tell me a small opensource project on Python (not Django) with good test coverage?

Tags: python, unit-testing, open-source

Who can tell me a small or middle opensource (for instance, on Github) project on Python (not Django) with good test coverage, using `unittest`. I've read some books and articles about this theme and I want to get practice of unittest. See real unittest code in real project.

Comment: Most of the modules in the Python library itself have test packages.  Python has a lot of testing.   What's wrong with the tests that came with Python itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd also look into using nosetests, you can write your tests in the unittest style if you like or in a more modular way.  In order to get coverage using nosetests all you need to do is tack on the --with-coverage modifier on the command line. Also if you just want good coverage of your code as it's executed I'd use the actual coverage module http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/ you can import it into your project and use it programmatically as well.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) ([Github](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask)) and how they handle [unittests](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/).